# Handling "The openssl extension is missing: in XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp, php-openssl

I tried to Install composer on my PC (Windows 8 Pro 64x and XAMPP 3.2.1), so I downloaded Windows Installer and run it
But I got this error:

> *The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.*

I searched about this problem and I tried some solutions

> extension=php_openssl.dll

was uncomment in php.ini file in *C:\xampp\php\php.ini* and there's no other php.ini file on my system (I searched for it)

Also when I run "php --ini" command in CMD, I get this:

> Configuration File (php.ini) Path: C:\windows
>
> Loaded Configuration File:         (none)
>
> Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
>
> Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

if it helps.

I hope someone helps me. Tnx

Comment: since php says it's looking for a .ini file in c:\windows, the one you edited in c:\xampp is basically useless.

Comment: But there's no php.ini file in c:\windows. is there any way to change it or add XAPMM php.ini file to "Loaded Configuration File"?

Comment: exactly, so php's running with compiled-in defaults.

Comment: So is there any way to change it or add C:\xampp\php\php.ini file to "Loaded Configuration File"?

Comment: never used xampp. no idea why it'd be looking in c:\windows, which is a pretty stupid place for php to be storing its config. c:\windows should be hands-off for anyone but microsoft and driver writers these days.

Answer (score 1):

";extension=php_openssl.dll" is commented out in the php.ini file. Simply remove the comment, save the file, rerun the Composer Install.

Answer (score 1):

I've been battling the same issue since last week but was able to solve it today. First, I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10, so you're home as long as you've got XAMPP running on your PC.

(You may run phpinfo.php to know your settings (you can create a simple script file with that name , check for extension_path. It should point to the 'php\ext' folder (that's where mine is)) I set the path in php.ini to c:\xampp\php\ext. You can get to this file from the XAMPP control panel by clicking on CONFIGURE button corresponding to APACHE web server then, select 'php.ini' from the pop list. Search for extension_path and remove the comment directive (';').

Remember to stop and restart Apache web server from the XAMPP Control Panel.

That's all I did, my php code isn't much different from the one above. Try this and let me know how you fare.

Answer (score 0):

`C:\xampp\php\php.ini` is the correct configuration file. Edit it and then make sure to restart Apache service for the change to take effect.

Comment: I tried this before, and it didn't work
finally I put a copy of my php.ini file in C:\windows and it worked, but it seems dirty

Comment: In any case. `phpinfo()` should tell you exactly where the configuration is loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had this error while installing composer in my PC, try this:

1- Open C:\php\php.ini

2- Find **;extension=openssl** and remove **;** , save it

3- Now go to

> C:\xampp\php\ext

4- Copy all files

5- Now go to

> C:\php\ext

6- Paste these files

Try now :)
plz let me know if I did anything wrong

Comment: is the `Open C:\php\php.ini ....` should be included in your steps? if so, you can revise this answer to  include that step.